# How to change ARC text label based on condition Vega-Lite

Tags: vega-lite

I'm trying to change the text label based on a condition. But when I add the condition as seen below the position changes.

[Labels on the right position but no conditional formating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGvjG.png)

Tried to add (after row 75):

```
    "color": {
      "condition": {
        "test": "datum['Omzet Delta %'] < 0",
        "value": "red"},
        "value": "green"
      }
```

[Labels not on the right position but got the conditional formating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jxxG.png)

[Link to code in Vega-Lite editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygG4QDYFcCmBneBtUAwtBgOYD2ATgJYbwgCCIANCMurXAEwAcLbmneAAYAdAFYAvk0LFy1DiABCzVqkzwxYvmoyC4ARhGcpMqKUo06BFfw4AWAMzb2e0dxMgiZuZbggAIjY68JxCzgLwhvqS0p6yFgoAokHskVqqLpEi+h5e5vJ0AGIp6nDcduG6kRIAulIgUBQQAHZYAGaUALZ4oADGqL1oKMR0kFBonSK2APT6QvMLKhA4fgDynQBeGFCCtSwYzb1kYFTNJPCgUAAW27AIIG00KGB0tipQAJ4ADgoAjmgtKBUGBAxC0FhYGC9ADWdGaXVQVC2IHqRxQlAuDyeLz8eR84Ia3wU8M6p1QKiw-RQHFATTOHFwIAAxHZCgB2ByKbgqJlCACcigcfMCLCZhX0fIAbA5GKLJZLFIVJSLmdw2dwHIViqL9ARONLBKK1fQHNxrKL-Ip-IVEnYeQ4xHyBdyLYVFYqeXZ6AQxIplKKxErFMqeW7uDx9KG7P5OGJZcy2YVuHzuPGmfRo-5EslRYV-PQuXyecHjebmTwOamefR1Untcz9JLk9whDzOHyHQ42cXFF6vcXHWJY562WIhEOeZL6Hy3a3RVa2dE5wne+zIzre-4xGWmWyhJL98veYVt5oebrOA5h3UWNSSAccW1UFgMBJ6sMPhgKD0QJ0IBRYXuT4fjof9ehUU5mi-AAlCATjQFYWxYMg0DMChYPglZ9FCFgoDIMgUCBL54EaTA31iP8AMxYCFDMAAPKAVCaTDIjsMIHjIZooAAZSRDhsJYDouIAdQwKgSCuRi-HhCg-xQFQ6NWNo2hfKT2I+JSVO2YR6gOI4TjOaiMAYzFHgwZ5Xh0Q1CRA6SyFJZpyTfDxKMAy4iToejGJYZiqAQyJ5kEzieL4yJOCCkSxIkqSQBkuSVEeFB5L8JlLWtW0VAAI2pZocRAK5-zAABaFBxMklF9kOY5TnOIDjKk0AzIsvw3lwjy-H+QFgWgKgwQShEYuyNoUTfOogA)

Comment: Please mark as solve and/or upvote if your question was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

[image]

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"Categorie": "A", "value": 28, "value2": 0.5},
      {"Categorie": "B", "value": 55, "value2": 1.2},
      {"Categorie": "C", "value": 43, "value2": 0.8},
      {"Categorie": "D", "value": 20, "value2": 1.15},
      {"Categorie": "E", "value": 15, "value2": 1.1},
      {"Categorie": "F", "value": 84, "value2": 1}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [{"calculate": "datum.value/1000000", "as": "Omzet2"}],
  "encoding": {
    "theta": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative", "stack": "normalize"},
    "color": {
      "field": "Categorie",
      "type": "nominal",
      "scale": {
        "range": [
          "#4F73B8",
          "#09B39D",
          "#F1963A",
          "#66BF6D",
          "#8783FF",
          "#1C2632",
          "#87A38C",
          "#DBDFE4",
          "#3599B8",
          "#DFBFBF",
          "#4AC5BB",
          "#5F6B6D",
          "#FB8281",
          "#F4D25A",
          "#7F898A",
          "#A4DDEE",
          "#FDAB89",
          "#B687AC",
          "#28738A",
          "#A78F8F",
          "#168980",
          "#293537",
          "#BB4A4A",
          "#B59525",
          "#475052",
          "#6A9FB0",
          "#BD7150",
          "#7B4F71",
          "#1B4D5C",
          "#706060",
          "#0F5C55",
          "#1C2325"
        ]
      },
      "legend": false
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "arc",
        "innerRadius": 80,
        "outerRadius": 120,
        "tooltip": true
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "radius": 140,
        "fontSize": 12,
        "fontWeight": "normal",
        "xOffset": 0,
        "yOffset": 0, "fill":{"signal":"datum['Omzet2'] < 0.00005?'red':'green'"}
      },
      "encoding": {
        "text": {"field": "value2", "type": "nominal"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "radius": 100,
        "fontSize": 12,
        "fontWeight": "normal",
        "fill": "#DBDFE4",
        "blend": "hard-light"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "text": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative", "format": ".1f"}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```